# How does IntRange.random() introduce entropy in Kotlin

Tags: random, kotlin

I'm planning on using `IntRange.random()` (i.e. `(0..9999).random()`) to generate a random 5 digit code in **Kotlin**. It's important that malicious people cannot predict the sequence of numbers that will be generated.

Does `IntRange.random()` ensures that there is entropy when generating these numbers? i.e. How is the seed generated and is a new seed generated each time `IntRange.random()` is called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/f7337cc9fc2df91bec87537a12050ad978b61ba1/libraries/stdlib/jdk8/src/kotlin/random/jdk8/PlatformThreadLocalRandom.kt) you can find the JDK-platform specific implementation of the random used in Kotlin when you're on the JDK. As you can see, the implementation is based on `ThreadLocalRandom`, which isn't cryptographically secure as per its documentation:

```
Instances of `ThreadLocalRandom` are not cryptographically
secure.  Consider instead using `java.security.SecureRandom` in 
security-sensitive applications.
```

For your use case, you can consider adding a custom secure random generator like this:

```
fun IntRange.secureRandom() =
    SecureRandom().apply {
        nextBytes(ByteArray(20))
    }.nextInt((endInclusive + 1) - start) + start
```

This can be called on ranges of `Int`:

```
(0..10).secureRandom()
```

In the implementations shown, you can see that `SecureRandom` is being created over and over again, and you might want to think about caching it. It is being self-seeded (as opposed to explicitly seeded) to improve entropy.

Alternatively, you can create your own [`kotlin.random.Random`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/index.html) instance and pass it to [`IntRange::random(random: Random)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/random.html) instead, this time with a re-used instance of `SecureRandom`:

```
class SekureRandom : Random() {
    private val secureRandom = SecureRandom().apply {
        nextBytes(ByteArray(20))
    }

    override fun nextBits(bitCount: Int) =
        secureRandom.nextInt(bitCount)

}
```

That can be used like this:

```
(0..10).random(SekureRandom())
```

---

**NOTE:** Please find out about ways to improve this even further [here](https://www.veracode.com/blog/research/cryptographically-secure-pseudo-random-number-generator-csprng) for example.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed response! The secureRandom() function would create and use a new seed each time to generate an int within a given range right? Also, by cryptographically secure does that mean that SecureRandom ensures entropy so that a malicious actor can't predict the sequence of seeds being used?

Comment: I updated my answer, you should seed this yourself. In the current implementation, the instance is re-created and the seeds are set every time the method is invoked

Comment: How does self seeding with ByteArray(20) improve entropy over the seed being generated by SecureRandom?

Comment: As you can read in the article I linked, you should not rely on the seed the class generated.

Comment: Oh I see! You're right, the article explains it in more detail. Thanks for all of the help!